# How to make the banner appear on a certain page/section?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to display the `secondbanner` only on a certain page, but the problem I am facing right now is that it appears **as soon** the user scrolls down the website. But what I want is for it to appear only once it hits a certain section. Here is an example:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  let executionFlag = true;
  const toastSecond = document.getElementById("toastSecond");

  const toastCloseSecond = document.getElementById("toastCloseSecond");

  window.onscroll = function(b) {
    if (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY >= document.body.offsetHeight - 900 && executionFlag) {
      toastSecond.classList.add("open1");
      executionFlag = false;
    }
  };

  toastCloseSecond.addEventListener("click", function() {
    toastSecond.classList.remove("open1");
  });

})
```

```css
/* SecondBanner */

html1,
body1 {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.exponea-banner1 {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #2e364d;
  color: #ebeef7;
  padding: 30px 80px 30px 35px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  display: none;
  z-index: 9999999999;
}

.open1 {
  display: block;
}

.exponea-banner1 .exponea-close1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 300;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.exponea-banner1 .exponea-label1 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.exponea-banner1 .exponea-text1 {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.exponea-banner1 .exponea-count1 {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.exponea-banner1 .exponea-label1 {
  text-align: left;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
```

```html
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>

<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>

<br>
<section>
  <h2>Section I want the banner to appear in</h2>
</section>
<br>

<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>
<section>
  random text here
</section>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/banner.css">
<script src="assets/js/bannerclose1.js"></script>
<div class="exponea-banner1" id="toastSecond">
  <div class="exponea-close1" id="toastCloseSecond">&times;</div>
  <div class="exponea-text1"> Thanks for visiting!
  </div>
  <div class="exponea-label1">- Hussain Omer</div>
</div>
```

The above code actually works fine because Stack Overflow creates a reference, but on my end, it doesn't work as shown above. Can someone take a look: https://repl.it/join/dasyglsi-hussainomer

In the above code, I have provided an example where the banner should appear in the bolded section which is shown in the code above. When the user hits that section, then the banner should appear or pop up otherwise it shouldn't. Right now, **it pops up as soon as you scroll** but I want it to pop up only on the section I highlighted in the above code.

Comment: Use this instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API (also, repl.it wants me to login, plus you need to put code in your question that replicates the problem, or people will vote to close it)

Comment: Well, that's the issue. StackOverFlow and I believe some other IDEs are fine with the above code, it's just repl.it that's making this error. And I cannot switch from repl.it to another IDE cuz I am supposed to use that. Can you just create an account real quick and help please?

Comment: How does this differ from the three previous questions you've asked with nearly the same title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a fixed number of pixels to subtract from the screen height

Instead, you should use a percentage of the height

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
let executionFlag = true;
const toastSecond = document.getElementById("toastSecond");

const toastCloseSecond = document.getElementById("toastCloseSecond");



window.onscroll = function (b) {
      const percentToScroll = 0.7; //0.7 of the page
  if (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY >= document.body.offsetHeight * percentToScroll && executionFlag) {
    

    toastSecond.classList.add("open1");
    executionFlag = false;
  }
};

toastCloseSecond.addEventListener("click", function () {
  toastSecond.classList.remove("open1");
});

})
```

```css
/* SecondBanner */
html1,
body1 {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}



.exponea-banner1 {
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #2e364d;
  color: #ebeef7;
  padding: 30px 80px 30px 35px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  display: none;
  z-index: 9999999999;
}
.open1 {
  display: block;
}

.exponea-banner1 .exponea-close1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 300;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
.exponea-banner1 .exponea-label1 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
.exponea-banner1 .exponea-text1 {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.exponea-banner1 .exponea-count1 {
  font-weight: 500;
}
.exponea-banner1 .exponea-label1 {
  text-align: left;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
```

```html
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>

<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>

<br>
<section>
<h2>Section I want the banner to appear in</h2>
</section>
<br>

<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>
<section>
random text here
</section>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/banner.css"> 
 <script src="assets/js/bannerclose1.js"></script>
<div class="exponea-banner1" id="toastSecond">
  <div class="exponea-close1" id="toastCloseSecond">&times;</div>
  <div class="exponea-text1"> Thanks for visiting!
  </div>
  <div class="exponea-label1">- Hussain Omer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesnt seem to work. Check this out: https://repl.it/join/gmprptdy-hussainomer

Comment: Hey, are u able to see my messages on the repl.it site?

Comment: Hey man, I got it to work all I had to do was change the name of the classes:)